# Circleci fails bower install with - ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, bower, circleci

[Circleci](https://circleci.com/) keeps failing with this error
`ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular`

These are my dependencies in bower.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.7",
    "angular-animate": "1.4.7",
    "angular-credit-cards": "2.3.5",
    "angular-local-storage": "0.2.2",
    "angular-messages": "1.4.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.4.7",
    "angular-translate": "2.7.2",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.15",
    "bluebird": "2.9.34",
    "bourbon": "4.2.6",
    "immutable": "3.7.5",
    "neat": "1.7.2",
    "normalize-scss": "3.0.3",
    "ramda": "0.16.0",
    "rxjs": "2.5.2",
    "system.js": "0.19.6",
    "angular-markdown-directive": "0.3.1",
    "angularjs-geolocation": "0.1.1",
    "angulartics": "0.20.2",
    "angulartics-google-analytics": "0.1.2",
    "angulartics-facebook-pixel": "0.1.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.4.7"
  }
```

I tried running it locally and it works fine, not sure what's the problem. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

add

```
"ignoredDependencies": ["angular"]
```

to your bower.cc file and it will ignore the dependancy (but you must be sure yourself that the package works with your version of angular).